# Multiple styles in wpf

Tags: wpf, xaml

I want to define the design of my `TextBox` from static resource, how to apply that?

For now I have:

```
<TextBox  Style="{StaticResource TextBoxHeight }" />
```

And here `Page.Resources`:

```
<Page.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="TextBoxHeight" TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}" >
            <Setter Property="Height" Value="20"/>

        </Style>
        <Style x:Key="TextBoxBorder" TargetType="{x:Type Border}"  >
            <Setter Property="CornerRadius" Value="10"/>
        </Style>
 </Page.Resources>
```

But I need that:

```
<TextBox   Style="{StaticResource TextBoxHeight }" Style="{StaticResource TextBoxBorder }" />
```

But it gives error "The property 'Style' is set multiple times"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't set the `Style` property more than once. And you can't apply a `Style` with a `TargetType` of `Border` to a `TextBox`. But putting an implicit `Border` style in the `Resources` dictionary of the `Button` style should work:

```
<Style x:Key="TextBoxHeight1" TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}" >
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="20"/>
    <Style.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Border}">
            <Setter Property="CornerRadius" Value="10"/>
        </Style>
    </Style.Resources>
</Style>
```